# Bash for loop only does one iteration

Tags: bash

I cannot figure out what is going on here:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -e

for i in {0..24}
do
  echo "ping -c 1 10.11.1.$i"
  ping -c 1 10.11.1.$i
done

echo "done"
```

If I run this, it pings the first host and quits. Strangely, I don't even see the final "done" outside of the loop. If I remove the ping command, it prints everything as expected.

Can anyone tell me why this won't run? 
Bash version 5.0.16(1)-release from $BASH_VERSION

Comment: Then why did you do `set -e`?

Comment: That's it, I overlooked that.

Comment: As @KamilCuk said you should remove `set -e` (Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.) So if the first ping fails, it exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `set -e` from script to continue even if ping reports packet loss.

Comment: Alternatively, append `|| true` to the command that might fail.

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
for i in $(seq 0 24);
```

example:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in $(seq 200 210); do
ping -c 1 192.168.31.$ip | grep "bytes from" | cut -d ' " -f4 | cut -d ":" -f1 &
done
```

Comment: Replacing the brace expansion has nothing to do with the observed problem.